# Wordpress $wpdb->get_var results in blank page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get the simplest Wordpress database function to return a result and it shows up blank. The query works fine in phpMyAdmin and returns the result I want, but not via a page template in Wordpress.

This function is running on a page template that's based off the twentythirteen theme `page.php` (I simply replaced the `the_content()` with my function).  Code Below:

```
<?php
function ag_get_count_to_work(){
    global $wpdb;
    $num_posts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts");
    if ($num_posts) {
       echo "<h1>" . $num_posts . "</h1>";
    } else {
       die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

I might not have the `if` statement setup correctly, but even trying without the `if` statement (i.e., JUST return the result), the result is always blank, and there are no errors shown.  Can some eagle-eyed developer tell me what I'm missing please?

This is not the final function I want, but I'm just trying to break the problem down to its origin and this might be it.

Comment: Make a `var_dump` debug output of what the function call returns.

Comment: Do you ever actually call your function? Post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  GBroe, I'm not quite sure how to implement that.  I added    var_dump($num_posts); to my code and it didn't show anything.  Is that the correct way to do it?   Ed, I believe the function is called every time the page is loaded because it's on the php page template, is that not correct?  Crap, you're right... I just called the function on the page template using    ag_get_count_to_work(); and it returned the number of posts from the database.  I always thought if you put a function on a php page it was run when the page was loaded.  Rookie rookie rookie.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the function was defined but not called.  Probably because I'm so used to putting functions in the functions.php file.  Once it was called it seems to work fine.